# Those who were or those who are?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I'm confused whether to use were or are on this...

I detest liars, especially those who were/are making it up as a go-to-excuse.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use both. Depends on how you want to interpret that part. If the action is a present thing, which seems like a case in this instance, then you can go ahead with the present form. The past could mean that you detest only those who lied to you in the past. A bit off, but still acceptable.